# 3 Table MySQL JOIN Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

This MYSQL Query gets the users from a SugarCRM Database

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

I use this MySQL query to get the Email address of a User from a SugarCRM database...

```
SELECT email_address FROM `email_addr_bean_rel`
LEFT JOIN `email_addresses` ON `email_addresses`.id = `email_addr_bean_rel`.email_address_id
WHERE `bean_id` LIKE '1' 
AND `bean_module` LIKE 'Users'
AND `email_addresses`.deleted = 0
AND primary_address = 1
```

I need help building a SQL query to JOIN these as my goal is to build a User List of all users in a SugarCRM Database and have there primary email address be part of there user data.

IN the EMail SQL above the part `WHERE`bean_id`LIKE '1'` the number 1 is the User ID from the Users table.

The `id` column is what should be used to join the Users table to this email SQL.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*
      ,email_address
 FROM users
      LEFT JOIN email_addr_bean_rel
             ON email_addr_bean_rel.bean_d=users.id
            AND email_addr_bean_rel.bean_module = 'Users'
            AND email_addr_bean_rel.primary_address = 1
            AND email_addr_bean_rel.deleted = 0
      LEFT JOIN email_addresses
             ON email_addresses.id = email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id
            AND email_addresses.deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    SELECT u.*, ea.email_address
    FROM users AS u
    INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel AS eab ON (eab.bean_id = u.id AND eab.bean_module = 'Users' AND eab.primary_address = 1)
    INNER JOIN email_addresses AS ea ON (ea.id = eab.email_address_id AND ea.deleted = 0)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried that and I got this error message: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` = 'Users' AND eab.primary_address = 1)
INNER JOIN email_addresses AS ea ON (ea' at line 3 `  http://i.imgur.com/BKdOhMQ.png

Comment: When I removed the problem ` I now got this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'eab.email_address' in 'field list' `

Comment: The fix seems to be changing `eab.email_address` into `email_address` in the 1st line `SELECT`

Comment: I actually need to modify some more.  Right now it will return 2 or more records for the same User ID if the user has more than 1 email address.  I need to make it only return 1 user per user ID, any ideas?

Comment: why user can have more than 1 email? ok lets try to group by user.id